# Eclipse CDT и Makefile

Tags: cdt, makefile, eclipse

Есть проект на Си в Эклипсе, который использует встроенный сборщик. Есть ли возможность перевести этот проект на Makefile? По возможности нужна автоматическая генерация Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сменил в свойствах проекта -> Tool Chain Editor на Gnu Make Builder.
При первой компиляции появились соответствующие Makefile. 
Раньше вроде пробовал так, не получалось. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще мои эклипс собирает всегда прогу через makefile, поэтому может вам стоит полазить в project->Properties?